# Is it possible to split an audio recording that has two audio recordings in one

Tags: audio-recording

So basically I put my phone on record to record that day but at the same time someone else got a hold of my phone and started listening to another recording so both were on that recording is there an app or a tool that I can use to split the recording

Comment: There are 'source separation' tools that are used to extract stems from a mastered track but if both the recordings are of same type (say, human voices) it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you were recording via microphone, and someone played some other recording that has been recorded via microphone as well.

If you have access to the recording that has been played on your phone, and get recorded, you can try to put both of them on two tracks in a DAW, align: time, amplitude, and put in opposite phase. With some luck the other recording may partially cancel.

The main limitation is that playing back the recording via phone speakers and recording it back introduces many distortions. You may try to record the other recording again via the phone microphone again, and use that recording to subtract.

I wouldn't count on getting a perfectly clean result, but maybe you can remove some of the interference this way.

Answer (score 0):

No.

This would be the equivalent of trying to get the eggs & sugar back out of a cake.

Comment: Actually https://moises.ai/ gets the eggs and sugar surprisingly well. Not exactly what OP asked about, but who knows how it will develop?

Comment: There are several apps that will remove or isolate 'stems' from a coherent mix. That's not what the OP asked for though. This is the current sound.se QA on the topic, always open to new answers - https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/48818/9601